# Nearby search on Google Maps returns INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: google-maps

The request `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=10,10&key=MY_API_KEY` returns `INVALID_REQUEST` status.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby) doesn't say so

**[Required Parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#required-parameters)**

> **location**
> The point around which to retrieve place information. This must be specified as latitude,longitude.

**[Optional parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#optional-parameters)**

`<snip>`

> **radius**
> Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results. You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. Doing so instructs the Places service to prefer showing results within that circle; results outside of the defined area may still be displayed. 
> ...

Apparently, radius is also required in this instance, when included (along with a valid key), the service returns a response:

**without radius**:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=10%2C10&key=API_KEY

**result:**

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

**with radius:**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=10%2C10&radius=1500&key=API_KEY

**result:**

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 10.030721,
               "lng" : 9.988080399999999
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 10.03520199843268,
                  "lng" : 9.996601970331641
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 10.00131293531991,
                  "lng" : 9.975768926313542
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png",
         "icon_background_color" : "#7B9EB0",
         "icon_mask_base_uri" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
         "name" : "Lugge",
         "place_id" : "ChIJQZZJ8gEcVRARwMIZcx4oNvU",
         "reference" : "ChIJQZZJ8gEcVRARwMIZcx4oNvU",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ],
         "vicinity" : "Lugge"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```